# Не сохраняются данные в базу данных Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, база-данных

Вот мои модели:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLES = (
        ('Автор тестов', 'Автор тестов'),
        ('Преподаватель', 'Преподаватель'),
        ('Студент', 'Студент'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLES)
    
class TestAuthor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='test_author')
    

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(TestAuthor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def logical_delete(self):
        self.is_deleted = True
        self.save()

class Question(models.Model):
    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        ('Уникальный выбор', 'Уникальный выбор'),
        ('Множественный выбор', 'Множественный выбор'),
    )
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
    text = models.TextField()

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Program(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Result(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Вот функция представления создания теста:

```py
@login_required
def create_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_form = TestForm(request.POST)
        question_formset = QuestionFormSet(request.POST, prefix='question')
        choice_formsets = [ChoiceFormSet(request.POST, prefix=f'choice-{i}') for i in range(question_formset.total_form_count())]

        if test_form.is_valid() and question_formset.is_valid() and all([formset.is_valid() for formset in choice_formsets]):
            test = test_form.save(commit=False)
            test_author, _ = TestAuthor.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            test.author = test_author
            test.save()

            for question_form, choice_formset in zip(question_formset, choice_formsets):
                question = question_form.save(commit=False)
                question.test = test
                question.save()

                for choice_form in choice_formset:
                    choice = choice_form.save(commit=False)
                    choice.question = question
                    choice.save()


    else:
        test_form = TestForm()
        question_formset = QuestionFormSet(prefix='question')
        choice_formsets = [ChoiceFormSet(prefix=f'choice-{i}') for i in range(question_formset.total_form_count())]
    
    context = {
        'test_form': test_form,
        'question_formset': question_formset,
        'choice_formsets': choice_formsets,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'testapp/create_test.html', context)
```

Вот мои формы:

```py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('title',)

class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['text', 'is_correct']

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['text', 'question_type']



QuestionFormSet = forms.formset_factory(form=QuestionForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
ChoiceFormSet = forms.formset_factory(ChoiceForm, extra=4, can_delete=True)
```

И вот шаблон:

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'create_test' %}" id="create-test-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  
  <!-- Форма для создания теста -->
  {{ test_form.as_p }}
  
  <h3>Вопросы</h3>
  <div id="questions-container">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <div class="question-form">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <div class="choices-container">
        {% for choice_form in form.choice_forms %}
        <div class="choice-form">
          {{ choice_form.choice_text }}
          {{ choice_form.is_correct }}

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" id="add-question-btn">Добавить вопрос</button>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Создать тест">
</form>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var addQuestionBtn = document.getElementById('add-question-btn');
    var questionsContainer = document.getElementById('questions-container');

    addQuestionBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var questionForm = document.createElement('div');
      questionForm.classList.add('question-form');

      // Создание полей для вопроса
      var questionInput = document.createElement('input');
      questionInput.type = 'text';
      questionInput.name = 'form-' + (questionsContainer.childElementCount - 1) + '-question_text';
      questionInput.placeholder = 'Вопрос';
      questionInput.required = true;

      var questionTypeSelect = document.createElement('select');
      questionTypeSelect.name = 'form-' + (questionsContainer.childElementCount - 1) + '-question_type';
      questionTypeSelect.classList.add('question-type-select');
      questionTypeSelect.required = true;


      var multipleOption = document.createElement('option');
      multipleOption.value = 'Множественный выбор';
      multipleOption.text = 'Множественный выбор';


      var uniqueOption = document.createElement('option');
      uniqueOption.value = 'Уникальный выбор';
      uniqueOption.text = 'Уникальный выбор';

      questionTypeSelect.appendChild(uniqueOption);
      questionTypeSelect.appendChild(multipleOption);

      // Создание полей для ответов
      var choicesContainer = document.createElement('div');
      choicesContainer.classList.add('choices-container');

      var numChoices = 4;
      for (var i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
        var choiceForm = document.createElement('div');
        choiceForm.classList.add('choice-form');

        var choiceInput = document.createElement('input');
        choiceInput.type = 'text';
        choiceInput.name = 'form-' + (questionsContainer.childElementCount - 1) + '-choice_forms-' + i + '-choice_text';
        choiceInput.placeholder = 'Ответ';
        choiceInput.required = true;

        var choiceCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
        choiceCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
        choiceCheckbox.name = 'form-' + (questionsContainer.childElementCount - 1) + '-choice_forms-' + i + '-is_correct';

        var choiceLabel = document.createElement('label');
        choiceLabel.textContent = 'Правильный';

        choiceForm.appendChild(choiceInput);
        choiceForm.appendChild(choiceCheckbox);
        choiceForm.appendChild(choiceLabel);
        choicesContainer.appendChild(choiceForm);
      }

      questionForm.appendChild(questionInput);
      questionForm.appendChild(questionTypeSelect);
      questionForm.appendChild(choicesContainer);

      questionsContainer.appendChild(questionForm);
    });

    // Обработчик изменения типа вопроса
    questionsContainer.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var questionTypeSelect = event.target;
      if (questionTypeSelect.classList.contains('question-type-select')) {
        var questionForm = questionTypeSelect.parentNode;
        var choicesContainer = questionForm.querySelector('.choices-container');
        var choiceForms = choicesContainer.querySelectorAll('.choice-form');
        var questionType = questionTypeSelect.value;

        for (var i = 0; i < choiceForms.length; i++) {
          var choiceCheckbox = choiceForms[i].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
          var choiceRadio = choiceForms[i].querySelector('input[type="radio"]');

          if (questionType === 'Уникальный выбор') {
            choiceCheckbox.setAttribute('type', 'radio');} 
          else {
            choiceRadio.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Эта часть кода возвращает False:

```py
question_formset.is_valid()
```

Comment: Ну значит выводите ошибки из форм, чтобы узнать, почему False https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors